# Redirect Azure Website to HTTPS

Tags: php, azure

I have a PHP Application deployed on Azure Website. I have configured the SSL certificate under the configuration and now I need to redirect http request to https. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the same checks you would for php anywhere, not just in Azure. You should be able to check if it is on HTTPS with this:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off' || !isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || !$_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
    // request is not using SSL, redirect to https, or fail
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to add 'off' as condition as well to make it work. I am wondering if we can do this in the web server level rather writing relocation in the beginning of every page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way is to use a **web.config** for this purpose.

This rule will make sure all traffic is sent over SSL

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This is my default configuration for PHP apps on Azure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <clear />
            <!-- Rewrite rules to /public by @maartenballiauw *tnx* -->
            <rule name="TransferToPublic-StaticContent" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*images*" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*css*" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*js*" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="robots.txt" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="TransferToPublic" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
              <match url="*" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php" />
            </rule>
              <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                 <conditions>
                     <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
                 </conditions>
                 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
               </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```